# Given a column, x, I wish to count the number of trailing 0s and reset the count every time x is not equal to 0

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Take the following data as an example

```
+---+--------+----------+
| id|column_a|zero_count|
+---+--------+----------+
|  1|       0|         0|
|  2|       0|         0|
|  3|       0|         0|
|  4|       1|         3|
|  5|       0|         0|
|  6|       0|         0|
|  7|       0|         0|
|  8|       0|         0|
|  9|       1|         4|
| 10|       0|         0|
+---+--------+----------+
```

I wish to get from `column_a` to column `zero_count`, i.e. each time `column_a != 0`, I want to know how many 0s preceded it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using window functions.

Let's make your dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 0),
        (2, 0),
        (3, 0),
        (4, 1),
        (5, 0),
        (6, 0),
        (7, 0),
        (8, 0),
        (9, 1),
        (10, 0),
    ],
    ["id", "column_a"],
)
```

A possible solution looks like this (quite verbose because I'm keeping intermediary results so you can see what happens):

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

window = Window.orderBy("id")
df2 = df.select(
    "*",
    F.sum(F.lag("column_a").over(window)).over(window).alias("cumsum"),
    F.coalesce("cumsum", F.col("column_a")).alias("clean"),
)

>>> df2.show()
+---+--------+------+-----+
| id|column_a|cumsum|clean|
+---+--------+------+-----+
|  1|       0|  null|    0|
|  2|       0|     0|    0|
|  3|       0|     0|    0|
|  4|       1|     0|    0|
|  5|       0|     1|    1|
|  6|       0|     1|    1|
|  7|       0|     1|    1|
|  8|       0|     1|    1|
|  9|       1|     1|    1|
| 10|       0|     2|    2|
+---+--------+------+-----+


windowspec = Window.orderBy("id").partitionBy("clean")
df3 = df2.withColumn("row_nr", F.row_number().over(windowspec) - 1)

>>> df3.show()
+---+--------+------+-----+------+
| id|column_a|cumsum|clean|row_nr|
+---+--------+------+-----+------+
|  1|       0|  null|    0|     0|
|  2|       0|     0|    0|     1|
|  3|       0|     0|    0|     2|
|  4|       1|     0|    0|     3|
|  5|       0|     1|    1|     0|
|  6|       0|     1|    1|     1|
|  7|       0|     1|    1|     2|
|  8|       0|     1|    1|     3|
|  9|       1|     1|    1|     4|
| 10|       0|     2|    2|     0|
+---+--------+------+-----+------+


output = df3.select(
    "id",
    "column_a",
    F.when(F.col("column_a") != 0, F.col("row_nr"))
    .otherwise(F.lit(0))
    .alias("zero_count"),
)

>>> output.show()
+---+--------+----------+
| id|column_a|zero_count|
+---+--------+----------+
|  1|       0|         0|
|  2|       0|         0|
|  3|       0|         0|
|  4|       1|         3|
|  5|       0|         0|
|  6|       0|         0|
|  7|       0|         0|
|  8|       0|         0|
|  9|       1|         4|
| 10|       0|         0|
+---+--------+----------+
```

The general idea is:

- First we try to create groups which we can `partition_by` later on. We do that by calculating the cumulative sum (`cumsum` column). We use the `lag` function in there because the 1 occurences are part of the previous group of 0 values. Then we clean that `cumsum` column, that makes `df2`.
- Now we have the groups of data! We can use the `row_number()` function as a kind of "proxy" for the number of zeroes. We just need to do `- 1` because the row in which we have 1 does not count as a 0. That makes `df3`.
- Creating `output` is simple: just selecting the rows where `column_a` was != 0 to be equal to the row number value, else putting it on 0.

Assumptions:

- You want to orderBy the `id` column
- The way it's done in this example groups all the data onto 1 executor (since we're not using `partitionBy` on that first `window` object). This will not work with really big data. If you have really big data, you probably should have some other column on which you can `partitionBy`.

Comment: Looks pretty solid, thanks.